# How can we customize the logo and some text on the welcome screen?

Tags: admin, dashboard, screen-options

I have found discussions and solutions on hiding or removing the lately introduced **Welcome screen**.

But we DO find the screen, as a whole, very useful and an excellent addition. So, what we are looking for is quite different.

---

We just want to **change parts of it on a multisite/subfolders network**.

To be exact. The wp logo image (wp-badge.png) on the left, as well as the header next to it (.welcome-panel-content .about-description, .welcome-panel h3) and the text under it included in (.about-text, .about-description, .about-wrap li.wp-person a.web).

[image: Proposed Welcome Panel]

I am aware that most of it is hardcoded. Still.... There must be a way. :)

PS: 1) We already use a plugin that can add css on the admin screens. But I don't think it would solve anything.
2) If there is a way, please be as specific/descriptive as possible. My coding skills suck. :(

### Update

After following brasofilo's instructions I have compiled the code to a mu-plugin. I placed it in our mu-plugins folder, have tested it on our test-multisite and works like a charm. :)

I have it uploaded to my dropbox so anyone can benefit. Feel free to [Right Click Here](http://db.tt/eRHA0o4C), download it and customize it to your needs. I hope it helps others as well.

PS: @brasofilo Please let me know whether I have credited it correctly.

Comment: @toscho Thank you for editing (putting up the image) the post for me. Could you probably add a new tag "welcome screen"? I think it could be useful

Comment: The welcome screen is [under discussion](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2012/07/03/discuss-the-bigger-picture-3-5-and-beyond/) currently. I would rather wait until we have at least four questions about it before we add yet another tag.

Comment: Everything cool, marikamisos, glad to help :o) . . . . . But I think that, for a broader and *more direct* benefit, you can post your code as an Answer here (if not, a Gist would be better than a DropBox). And if you go and earn an [Analytical Badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical), you'll understand what I mean by *posting your own Answer* ;o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever we find ourselves in the situation "*there must be a way to overcome this hard-code*", jQuery comes to rescue...

#### The Result

[image]

#### The Code

The following code must be pasted at the end of the active Theme `functions.php` file.
Or it can be used in a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2819/12615), which will make the code "theme-independent".

```
add_action('admin_head-index.php', 'wpse_57350_script_enqueuer');

function wpse_57350_script_enqueuer()
{
    // Check if Welcome Panel is being displayed
    $option = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'show_welcome_panel', true );
    if( !$option )
        return;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*
         * Hide the Welcome Panel and the "dismiss" message at the bottom
         */ 
        #welcome-panel {opacity:0.01;} 
        p.welcome-panel-dismiss {display:none}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
    {
        /*
         * Left side image and text
         * - changing CSS properties and raw Html content of the Div
         */
        $('div.wp-badge').css('background-image','url(http://lifelabsnewyork.com/sitebuilder/images/brain-filled-173x192.jpg)');
        $('div.wp-badge').css('color','#000000');
        $('div.wp-badge').html('Custom Welcome');

        // Right side H3 (change raw Html content)
        $('div.welcome-panel-content h3').html('By StackExchange WordPress Answers');

        // Right side paragraph (idem)
        $('p.about-description').html('To be exact. The wp logo image (wp-badge.png) on the left, as well as the header next to it (.welcome-panel-content .about-description, .welcome-panel h3) and the text under it included in (.about-text, .about-description, .about-wrap li.wp-person a.web).');

        /*
         * Everything modified, fade in the whole Div
         * The fade in effect can be removed deleting this and the CSS opacity property
         */
        $('#welcome-panel').delay(300).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });     
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

> Note that I'm being lazy and printing the Styles and Scripts directly in the admin header.
>   Please refer to the following Q&A on how to do it in a proper/formal fashion.
>   [How do I enqueue styles/scripts on certain /wp-admin pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/41207/12615)
>   [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/21561/12615)

Comment: @marikamitsos : Haven't welcomed you to WPSE, consider it so! Please take a moment to read this Stack's [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). . . . . . Didn't mentioned in my answer, but it was easy after [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53035/12615) :)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :) Sorry. I didn't realize I canNOT do paragraphs and I also am a slow writer. So the clarifications: 1. I take it that all the text as well as the link to the image will be "hardcoded". 2. The whole "thing" sits as a blanket on top of the actual welcome screen so on the page source the two coexist (quite fine with me). 3. I must keep the wpse_57350_script_enqueuer intact???? I will be waiting for your answer. In the meantime I am off to the links you provided for some reading on how/where to apply your code -I don't have a clue. :( Thank you again

Comment: @marikamitsos : Yeah, apologies, you did said that in your Q. I've added relevant info and comments in the code... 1)Yes, it's all being re-written/re-styled inside that jQuery block. 2) No, we are making "live" changes in the Html using jQuery. 3) After pasting it in your theme's `functions.php`, you have to adapt the lines that contain `$('div.wp-badge')`, `$('div.welcome-panel-content h3')` and `$('p.about-description')` to suit your needs.

Comment: I do understand this is not an "Ignorants Support Forum" (like myself) but... So. The wpse_57350_script_enqueuer will be changed according to what? Also, since I try to use it on a multisite/subfolders, is there someway we could turn this to a mu-plugin (so it registers with all themes for all sites) instead of putting the code to every theme's functions.php? If so how can I do that? I am off to give it a try. Thanks again :)

Comment: Well, if you are talking about Multisite and `mu-plugins` why are you mentioning "ignorance"?! If you compare the code with the snapshot, you'll know what to do... But yes, just put a [plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and drop the file in the `mu-plugins` folder and voilà.